# Is there an R function to convert 'symbols' into normal characters?

Tags: r, character, symbols

[FIFA players names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oiHdq.png)

Is there a way to convert these special symbols to the original character? I'm new to learning R, so unsure of the correct function. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems you imported text encoded in a different encoding than the one specified in your locale. In this case, as the 'Ã©' should be an "é" it is probably a case of UTF-8 text read as a Latin1.
You could try to reread the source file and specify UTF-8 as the source's encoding.

Comment: @NicolásVelásquez This worked! Thanks so much.